# Determine if the sequence is time invariant or not

Tags: discrete-signals

Determine if the following sequence is time invariant or not:
$$y[n]= n^2x[n-2]$$

Comment: Hi there Rura. We do not answer homework questions here. However if you show what you've tried and where you're stuck, we'll gladly help ;)

Comment: What does it mean for a _sequence_ to be **time-invariant**? If a _sequence_ is time-invariant -- which could be interpreted as _not varying with time_ -- it must have the _same_. value at _all_ times, no??  Like $\cdots ~2~2~2~2~2~\cdots$??  And the test for time-invariance would be trivial.....